# Split variables in brackets with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have already tried google but I was not able to find an answer to my problem.

My javascript/jQuery so far:

```
$(function() {
    var faceGroup = ['clock-clock.png','clock-clock-2.png','clock-clock-3.png'];
    var arm1Group = ['clock-arm1.png','clock-arm1-2.png','clock-arm1-3.png'];
    var arm2Group = ['clock-arm2.png','clock-arm2-2.png','clock-arm2-3.png'];
    var arm3Group = ['clock-arm3.png','clock-arm3-2.png','clock-arm3-3.png'];
    var bulletGroup = ['clock-bullet.png','',''];

    $('button').click(function() {
        faceGroup.split(/*thirst click use clock-clock.png second click use clock-clock-2.png third click etc...*/);
        //do for everything
    });

    $('.holder').css('backgroundImage','url(' + faceGroup + ')');
    $('.hours').css('backgroundImage','url(' + arm1Group + ')');
    $('.minutes').css('backgroundImage','url(' + arm2Group + ')');
    $('.seconds').css('backgroundImage','url(' + arm3Group + ')');
    $('.bullets').css('backgroundImage','url(' + bulletGroup + ')');
});
```

How can I achieve that when you click the button it will first do the first variable in the brackets and the on the second click it will use the second variable.

so on first click use:

- clock-clock.png
- clock-arm1.png
- clock-arm2.png
- clock-arm3.png
- clock-bullet.png

and on the second click it need to use this:

- clock-clock-2.png
- clock-arm1-2.png
- clock-arm2-2.png
- clock-arm3-2.png
- clock-bullet-2.png

and this need to be continue for three clicks total and then it have to use the first variable again, I hope I have explained my problem it clearly.

Comment: @Blazemonger: `and this need to be continue for three clicks and then it have to use the first variable again,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a variable to keep track of the current index in your array(s) and update it on each click. For example:

```
var index = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
    var currFace = faceGroup[index];
    //do the same for your other arrays

    $('.holder').css('backgroundImage','url(' + currFace + ')');
    // etc

    // update index
    index = (index + 1) % faceGroup.length;     // Note we are assuming all the arrays are the same length!
});
```

Note that if you don't need the variable `currFace` for anything else, you can simply use `faceGroup[index]` in your `.css` line.

Another thought: It might be easier to replace you arrays with a single array of objects because that would make it easier to keep them lined up and prevent errors with, for example, adding an extra item to one array and forgetting to do it another. Something like this:

```
var clocks = [
    { 
        face: 'clock-clock.png', 
        arm1: 'clock-arm1.png', 
        arm2: 'clock-arm2.png',
        arm3: 'clock-arm3.png',
        bullet: 'clock-bullet.png' 
    },
    { 
        face: 'clock-clock-2.png', 
        arm1: 'clock-arm1-2.png', 
        arm2: 'clock-arm2-2.png',
        arm3: 'clock-arm3-2.png',
        bullet: '' }, // etc
]
```

And then you can get each property with:

```
var currFace = clocks[index].face;
var arm1 = clocks[index].arm1;
// etc
```

Comment: Thanks, for your great answer. Works correctly, only one question: what means the % on almost the end of the code?

Comment: @SakeSalverda: It's the [modulo (or remainder) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators). Appropriately, this trick of looping around with the `%` operator is sometimes called [clock arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store a counter variable. The cleanest way to do so is to use `.data()` to store it on the element itself:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var idx = $(this).data('counter') % faceGroup.length;
    if (!idx) idx = 0;
    var img = faceGroup[idx];
    $(this).data('counter', idx+1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/D9mve/

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable like `currentPosition` to store the respective element that is `clicked`.

```
var currentPosition = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
        faceGroup[currentPosition];
        //do for everything
        if (currentPosition === 2)
           currentPosition = 0; //reset once it is reaches the last element in the array
        else 
           currentPosition++;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to keep a record on how many clicks you've made. The button can do it itself with the `data` method.

```
$(function() {
    var faceGroup = ['clock-clock.png','clock-clock-2.png','clock-clock-3.png'];
    var arm1Group = ['clock-arm1.png','clock-arm1-2.png','clock-arm1-3.png'];
    var arm2Group = ['clock-arm2.png','clock-arm2-2.png','clock-arm2-3.png'];
    var arm3Group = ['clock-arm3.png','clock-arm3-2.png','clock-arm3-3.png'];
    var bulletGroup = ['clock-bullet.png','',''];

    $('button').click(function() {
        var clickedtimes=jQuery(this).data('clickedtimes') || 0;
        $('.holder').css('backgroundImage','url(' + faceGroup[clickedtimes] + ')');
        $('.hours').css('backgroundImage','url(' + arm1Group[clickedtimes] + ')');
        $('.minutes').css('backgroundImage','url(' + arm2Group[clickedtimes] + ')');
        $('.seconds').css('backgroundImage','url(' + arm3Group[clickedtimes] + ')');
        $('.bullets').css('backgroundImage','url(' + bulletGroup[clickedtimes] + ')');

       // bump index, reset if it's longer than the array length
       clickedtimes++;
       if(clickedtimes==faceGroup.length) clickedtimes=0;
       jQuery(this).data('clickedtimes',clickedtimes);

    });
```

});

On each click the inned clickedtimes counter gets bumped by one, thus moving the index in each picture array.